# Android Gradle plugin 3.0.1 must not be applied to project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I keep getting this error when I try to build my project. I have no idea what is wrong with it and nothing I try is working.

I've trying cleaning, restarting Android Studio, and stopping the daemon with gradlew --stop.

Please help me!

Error:

```
Android Gradle plugin 3.0.1 must not be applied to project since version 3.0.1 was already applied to this project
```

Module:app script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.joey.projectgenesis"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Project script

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Jan 12 20:21:58 EST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Why are you defining same set of values in two build.gradle files, at project / module level? Remove from project.script.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it so the project isn't the same as the module. The post is fixed now.

Comment: Are building a library?

Comment: remove apply plugin: 'com.android.library' so you build an app

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are creating just an app, remove `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

If you are creating a library replace `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and remove `applicationId`.

[Refer this - Creating Android Libraries](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was much more silly. While doing find and replace, I had updated the `versionCode` to have a value in decimal.

Older values:

`versionCode 253
versionName '2.53'`

Newer values:

`versionCode 2.54
versionName '2.54'`

Having 2.54 for `versionCode` caused the issue. Changing that back to `254` did the trick for me!